# Looping variables not replaced by their values

Tags: functions, programming

Sometimes **Table[ ]** leaves the looping variable in the output, instead of replacing it by the values.  For example

```
In[255]:= Table[{v, #[v] &, # /. x -> v &}, {v, {0, 1}}]
```

gives

```
Out[255]= {{0, #1[v] &, #1 /. x -> v &}, {1, #1[v] &, #1 /. x -> v &}},
```

instead of the desired

```
Out[255]= {{0, #1[0] &, #1 /. x -> 0 &}, {1, #1[1] &, #1 /. x -> 1 &}}.
```

Is there a way to force **Table[   , {v, {0,1}}]** to properly replace **v** by the values **0** and **1**??   Can anyone explain this bizarre behavior?

Comment: You could use a dummy variable `u` and then replace, as in `Table[{u, #[u] &, # /. x -> u &} /. u -> v, {v, {0, 1}}]`. Or not use `Table`: `{v, #[v] &, # /. x -> v &} /. Array[{v -> #} &, 2, 0]`.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What is the goal of this construction?

Comment: What is `#[v] &` supposed to give?  Can you give what is the expected output of `Table[{v, #[v] &, # /. x -> v &}, {v, {0, 1}}]`? It is not clear what you want to generate.

Comment: Nasser:  `#[1]&` is a pure function which sends the input `f` to the output `f[1]`.  Bill:  I was using such functions to as inputs to a somewhat abstract constrained optimization routine I wrote.  In particular, I wanted to use the above function tell the optimizer to optimize only over functions f which evaluated to certain values in certain places.  I found a work-around, but it very much bothers me when basic functions such as *Table[ ]* do unexpected things, so I want to know what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[With[{v = v}, {v, #[v] &, # /. x -> v &}], {v, {0, 1}}]
```

> {{0, #1[0] &, #1 /. x -> 0 &}, {1, #1[1] &, #1 /. x -> 1 &}}

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @JTyson, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.